# Unable to run selenium tests correctly in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I created some selenium tests. No issues to run locally. And I want to configure a Jenkins job to run the tests.Got the following error

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926) on port 6720
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1564522396.317][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

All the tests can not locate the web elements.

The chrome version in the docker image is 73. And the chrome driver I provide is 2.46(also tried with 73.0.3683.68) selenium-java 3.5.0

I tried many suggestions like
add `chmod +x src/test/resources/localWebDriver/chromedriver`

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--whitelisted-ips");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
```

But still can not run these tests correctly. Anyone met this problem before? Please help me, it took me hours to investigate the issue.

Additional information:

```
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
      System info: host: '9ecf345f97e8', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.121-85.96.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
      Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
      Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=false, goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:35983}, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=LINUX, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.79YB7v}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore, pageLoadStrategy=normal, strictFileInteractability=false, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=73.0.3683.103, browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy=Proxy(), nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
```

Comment: Check this issue https://github.com/RobCherry/docker-chromedriver/issues/15

Comment: selenium 3.5.3 is not compatible with new chrome,.  upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
      System info: host: '9ecf345f97e8', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.121-85.96.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
      Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *WebBrowser* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.46*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.46*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v71-73**

- You are using *chrome=73.0*
- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.5.3** of *2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z* which is almost **2** years older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_51** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u51* , *Selenium Client v3.5.3* , *ChromeDriver v2.46* and the *Chrome Browser v73.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  current levels [JDK 8u212](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current level [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [ChromeDriver v76.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.68/) level.
- Update *Chrome* to  current *Chrome Version 76.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v76.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.68/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test` as a **non root** user.